# Nautilus "Not authorized to perform operation" with xorg on arch

Tags: arch-linux, nautilus

When I try to mount a disk with nautilus on Arch by clicking on a drive under "Other Locations", I get the following error: "**Unable to access location - Not authorized to perform operation**".
From the error I would say this is a permission issue. I found a very [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434485/nautilus-doesnt-mount-in-xmonad-not-authorized-to-perform-operation), though sadly the described solution doesn't work on my system.

So how can I allow a normal user to mount drives? This question applies to arch, xorg with awesome.

---

Output of `journalctl -b -u polkit`

```
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch polkitd[1009]: Started polkitd version 121
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch polkitd[1009]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch polkitd[1009]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch polkitd[1009]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 5 rules
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Jul 23 10:58:39 arch polkitd[1009]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
Jul 23 11:03:00 arch polkitd[1009]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.106 [pkttyagent], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul 23 11:08:09 arch polkitd[1009]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.106, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul 23 11:12:41 arch polkitd[1009]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.232 [pkexec], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul 23 11:12:47 arch polkitd[1009]: Operator of unix-process:2231:28859 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:2231:28859 [/usr/bin/zsh] (owned by unix-user:marian)
Jul 23 11:12:47 arch polkitd[1009]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.232, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul 23 11:13:23 arch polkitd[1009]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.244 [pkexec nautilus], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jul 23 11:13:25 arch polkitd[1009]: Operator of unix-process:2231:28859 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:2231:28859 [/usr/bin/zsh] (owned by unix-user:marian)
Jul 23 11:13:25 arch polkitd[1009]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:2231:28859 (system bus name :1.244, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit#Authentication_agents (Also make sure you have udisks2 installed.)

Comment: Well this documentation tells me to add overwrite js functions in the `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` directory. The issue is that I don't even have permission to go into the directory `rules.d` folder... So I can't even edit/create a new rule

Comment: No, it tells you to install and (auto)start a polkit agent for GUI programs. (Why would you not have permission on your own machine though? Have problem setting up `sudo`?)

Comment: Well i checked if polkit was already installed and it was. So I tried opening the folders which are described there and I get a permission error.
I think sudo is configured correctly, at least I would tell that by the outpout of
`sudo -lU myUser`
`User myUser may run the following commands on arch: (ALL : ALL) ALL`

Comment: polkit agent != polkit, and the former needs to be started / run explicitly in your case (WM only / no "DE").

Comment: So the installed polkit agent must be started before the wm?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you are talking about e.g. `.xinitrc`, normally you have `exec` for the wm and hence all the other stuff you start there (with `&`) needs to be before the `exec`.

Comment: Oh I see, so I installed now a polkit agent (I randomly chose lxsession). It seems to be running without me needing to start it manually.
In your second comment you point out that the wiki tells me to install and start the agent, which I guess is done. Though isn't there the rules missing which takes over the permission part when opening nautilus? I mean for now nothing changed in terms of permissions.

Comment: `It seems to be running without me needing to start it manually.` No one knows how you determined the "seems". Add `journalctl -b -u polkit` to your question. `Though isn't there the rules missing which takes over the permission part when opening nautilus? I mean for now nothing changed in terms of permissions.` I have no idea what you are talking about. If this is about some problem you have with `sudo`, post another question for it.

Comment: For the record there's probably a way to override the polkit policy for / shipped with udisks2, which could probably allows you to mount filesystems on internal drives without requiring any authorization (hence no polkit agent needed). I'm not that familiar with polkit so I don't really know how to override the policy properly. But if you are looking for a way to mount it without entering any password (you haven't been clear on the current status btw), that (instead of polkit agent) is probably what you want to research on. (In other words, polkit agent is and is only for authorization AFAIK.)

Comment: When running nautilus with sudo, no drives appear at all. I don't think that this should be the case. I'll try to fix this first before trying to mount drives with a non root user. I'll come back here.

Comment: `sudo` / root is not supposed to make everything work. It does not exactly / always equal to "non-root user without limit", especially when it comes to GUI and/or things that involve "modern stuff" like user session or whatsoever. No point wasting your time diving into that. Btw your polkit log does not show lxpolkit even attempted to register itself to polkit, so no it is not running (which is pretty much expected since no WM does XDG autostart AFAIK).

Comment: You could really just run `lxpolkit` on any terminal emulator for testing. If it works then bother with autostarting.

Comment: Haha, I thought i was doing something wrong because I got no response so I always quit `lxpolkit` But yeah it works like this! I really appreciate your help.